# How to make the right side of the trackpad of a MacBook Air behave as a right click?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I have a MacBook Air running OS X El Capitan. No matter where I click on the built-in trackpad, it behaves as if I am left-clicking. To right-click, I must hold control, then click the trackpad. Is there any way to have the behavior changed, so that if I click in the right half of the trackpad, it behaves as a right click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how things are for the track pad preferences on MacBook air but on the MacBook Pro, go to trackpad settings on system preferences and you should see this..

[image]